# Можно ли сделать так, чтобы Sqlite не изменял регистр?

Tags: sqlite

Есть база данных, которая хранит ссылки на каналы YouTube.
Вот как выглядит то, что вводит пользователь:

```
 https://www.youtube.com/user/NewOnNetflix
```

А вот что сохраняется в таблице:

```
https://www.youtube.com/user/newonnetflix
```

Если в данном случае ссылка и так работает, то с некоторыми каналами регистр очень важен. Можно ли как то избежать этого?
P.s. Вот сам код:

```
 if '/подписка' in body:
    body=body[10:]
    id = [(user_id,body)]
    conn = sqlite3.connect("mydatabase.db")
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO id VALUES (?,?)", id)
    conn.commit()
    sql = "SELECT * FROM id WHERE channels=?"
    cursor.execute(sql,[(body)])
    cursor.execute("""DELETE FROM id WHERE ROWID NOT IN(SELECT MIN(ROWID) FROM id GROUP BY user,channels)""")
    message =('Ок, жди новых уведомлений')
    conn.close()
    return message, ''
```

Comment: Покажите схему таблицы и убедитесь, что `print(body)` содержит правильный регистр

Comment: Предъявляйте претензии тому программному средству, которое записывает данные в БД либо читает и показывает. SQLite не меняет регистр, сохраняя поступившие данные в UTF as is. У него даже по умолчанию COLLATION=BINARY, а если при сравнении указать иное, то приводится регистр только для ASCII-символов, т.е. у него поддержки UTF Collation тупо нет.

Comment: [Схема таблицы](https://imgur.com/a/Ru3SXew)

Comment: @Moroka8 это не схема таблицы, это просто её содержимое, которое нас не интересует. Вы `print(body)` проверили?

Comment: @andreymal Странно, но при попытке `print(body)` он выводит `None`

Comment: @andreymal [Схема таблицы](https://imgur.com/a/PllktfM)
Я надеюсь, это нужно было указать

Comment: @Akina Код выше написан на Python, следовательно, его винить за то, что регистр меняется?

Comment: Понятия не имею... смотри настройки коннектора, например - может, это его фортели?

Comment: @andreymal чуть посидев, `body` я все-таки вывел,и он в нижнем регистре. Это значит, что проблема в Python?